# Outlier detection using recursive curve fitting and error elimination

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, curve-fitting, outliers, best-fit-curve

Is there any way to do anomaly detection in dataset using recursive curve fitting and removing points having the most mean square error with respect to the curve, upto an acceptable threshold?

I am using the scipy.optimize.curve_fit function for python 2.7, and I need to work with python preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably speaking about recursive regression (which is quite easy in Matlab). For python, try and use the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

For a simple 3 degree polynomial fit, this would work based on `numpy.polyfit` and `poly1d`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (9, 3)])
# get x and y vectors
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Though my data sets are quite large, but let me try this.